# How to get a Postcode to show depending on if an AdhocID is NULL/NOT NULL

Tags: sql, excel, openedge, progress-db

I am currently trying to return postcodes for delivery addresses. The issue i am currently experiencing is some of these are Ad hoc addresses so would not refer to the companies standard `SiteID`. Every record has a `CompanySiteID` and this is the only point i can `JOIN ON` between the `Ordering Table` and the `Address Table`.

What I want the data to do or if it can be done in the from clause is to say if the `DeliveryCompanySiteID` is blank then return the postcode for the `AdHocDeliveryAddressID` if not find the `AddressID` for the site and then find the postcode for that `AddressID`

Below is a sample of the tables and what i currently get:

**Table 1 - order**

```
CompanySiteID   DeliveryCompanySiteID   InvoiceCompanySiteID AdHocDeliveryAddressID
 8613552                                      8613552            663401931
94823142            326963198                326963198  
633057107           634312178                565578092
```

**Table 2 - Address**

```
AddressID   AddPostCode
663401931    NG1 1PQ
123          S12 1TP
456          S1 9PU
789          S11 1TY
```

**Table 3 - company site**

```
CompanySiteID   AddressID
8613552       123
94823142      456
633057107     789
```

**Based on the code i am using below this is the result i am getting:**

```
Site ID Site        PostCode
8613552             S12 1TP
94823142            S1 9PU
633057107           S11 1TY
```

The reason i believe this is happening is because of my `JOIN` which is:

Reason why I get the current result is because my join asks: `JOIN SBS.PUB.Address Address_0 ON CompanySite_0.AddressID = Address_0.AddressID`

Unfortunately there is no other way to join the tables, So i feel i need something in place that effectively says if the `DeliveryCompanySiteID` is blank then return the postcode for the `AdHocDeliveryAddressID` if not find the `AddressID` for the site and then find the postcode for that `AddressID`

Please see a simplified version of my code:

```
SELECT 
 CompanySite_0.CompanySiteID
    , Address_0.AddPostCode AS 'Delivery Post Code'


 FROM 

   SBS.PUB.SopOrderItem SopOrderItem_0 
    JOIN SBS.PUB.CompanySite CompanySite_0 ON SopOrderItem_0.CompanySiteID = CompanySite_0.CompanySiteID
    JOIN SBS.PUB.Address Address_0 ON CompanySite_0.AddressID = Address_0.AddressID
```

**In the end i hope to be able to get to the position where based on the sample i showed above that the result should return as:**

```
Site ID Site      PostCode
8613552           NG1 1PQ            
94823142          S1 9PU
633057107         S11 1TY
```

**And not like:**

```
Site ID Site     PostCode
8613552          S12 1TP 
94823142         S1 9PU
633057107        S11 1TY
```

I hope i have explained this well enough as i am struggling to explain it to myself at the moment.

Comment: Your query contains tables and columns not mentioned before. Simplify - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @jarlh I have now cut my code down. This should show all the needed parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it in SQL Developer, hopefully it'll work with the Openedge SQL interpreter (which uses SQL-92, last I checked).

```
SELECT
  orderitem.COMPANYSITEID
  , ADDRESS.ADDPOSTCODE as "Delivery Post Code"
  FROM 
    ORDERITEM
    LEFT JOIN COMPANYSITE ON (CASE WHEN ORDERITEM.DELIVERYCOMPANYSITEID IS NULL THEN 
                                        ORDERITEM.ADHOCDELIVERYADDRESSID ELSE 
                                        ORDERITEM.COMPANYSITEID END ) = COMPANYSITE.COMPANYSITEID 
    JOIN address ON (CASE WHEN companysite.addressID IS NULL THEN 
                               ORDERITEM.ADHOCDELIVERYADDRESSID ELSE 
                               companysite.addressID end ) = address.addressID;
```

That gave me the result

```
 94823142   S1 9PU
633057107   S11 1TY
  8613552   NG1 1PQ
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I need to look at a couple of things as the results are slightly unexpected but as far as the theory for fixing the problem this is the exact thing i was looking for. Thank you.